# AngularJS : Getting ng-repeat element (template compiled) to manipulate in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

The HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">
    <ul id="myAccordion">
        <li class="bgDark main-tab-animation" ng-repeat="tab in accordionTabs"
            ng-class="{'first-child' : $first, 'trend' : $last}">
            <accordion-content data="tab"></accordion-content>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('AccordionCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.accordionTabs = [{type:'tab'},{type:'tab'},{type: 'tab'},{type:'tab'},{type:'tab'},{type:'tab'},{type:'trend'}];
});
```

My Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('accordionContent', function ($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
   var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
       var templateLoader, baseUrl = 'views/',
       templateMap = { tab: 'tab1.html', tab2: 'tab2.html'};
       var templateUrl = baseUrl + templateMap[contentType];
            templateLoader = $http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache});
      return templateLoader;
   };

    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var loader = getTemplate(scope.data.type);

            var promise = loader.success(function(html) {
                element.html(html);
            }).then(function (response) {
                element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
            });

            element.addClass('juhee');
        }
    };
});
```

In the directive Iam loading 2 different templates (for now the templates are static html).

Can someone explain me how can I manipulate the DOM e.g. adding a class to the repeating li element in the directive. Now I've solved this with ng-class. But I would like donig this in the directive, e.g. like this way ....

```
if(scope.$last){
 element.addClass("trend");
}
```

but it looks like the li elements from the ng-repeat are not rendered at the time Iam trying to manipulate them...
The log looks like this:

```
[accordion-content.ng-isolate-scope, ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]
```

How can I get the compiled or rendered element in the Directive to manipulate it e.g. adding  removing classes or setting css .... ?

Thxs for your time and help!
vladi